# How to return data in a factory method within Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

I'm an ionic/Angular n00b and I having trouble wrapping my head around how to do this.

I have a factory defined as such:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Calendars', function () {

     var calendars;
     var success = function(message) {
        calendars = message;
        return calendars;
     };
     var error   = function(message) {alert("Error: " + message)};

     window.plugins.calendar.listCalendars(success,error);

     return {
         all: function() {
             return calendars;
         },
        get: function(calendarId) {
            return calendars[calendarId];
        }
     }


});
```

And I'm trying to retrieve the calendars within my controller like this:

```
.controller('CalendarsCtrl', function($scope,Calendars) {

    $scope.calendars = Calendars.all();

})
```

The factory method is being called but the results are not available until the 'success' callback is invoked so the CalendarsCtrl is always undefined.

How to solve this?

Edit - I've corrected the call within the controller.  The same issue remains though, that the function does not return results until the success callback.

Comment: I notice you're not defining `calendars` outside of the `success` callback. But even after you do that, you should be retrieving the calendars in your controller with `$scope = Calendars.all()`

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use a promise.

First add the dependency $q

```
.factory('Calendars', function ($q) {
```

then in all() you do this

```
all: function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    window.plugins.calendar.listCalendars(function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }
    ,function(error) {
        deferred.reject(error); // something went wrong here
    });
    return deferred.promise;
```

now this will make the return **after** the data has been resolved (no more undefined).

One last thing, now when you get the data back at your controller you do this

```
var promise = Calendars.all();
promise.then(function(data) {
  console.log('Success: you can use your calendar data now');
}, function(error) {
  console.log('Failed for some reason:' + error);
});
```

You can read some more about promises here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

I know it's hard to grasp the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Angular factories are returning an object, in order to call their methods you must call them with Calendar.all() which will invoke the inner function.